Issue with cleveref
This document does not compile.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{counterOne}
\newcounter{counterTwo}
\newcounter{counterThree}
\renewcommand{\thecounterTwo}{\alph{counterTwo}}

\labelformat{counterTwo}{\textbf{\thecounterOne.(#1)}}

\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{counterOne}
\refstepcounter{counterTwo}
\stepcounter{counterThree}

\label{here} Here

\refstepcounter{counterTwo}

\label{there} There

It was \ref{here}.

It was \ref{there}.
\end{document}

The raised issue is:

15: Missing \endcsname inserted. 
\csname\endcsname  l.15 \stepcounter{counterThree}

Questions
What is the issue?
How to fix it?

cleveref  does some \edef in its code and that fails if you use things like \textbf in the labelformat.

@UlrikeFischer answered the first. for the second: \renewcommand\thecounterTwo{\textbf{\thecounterOne.(\alph{counterTwo})}}. if you need the value of the counter without the formatting elsewhere, you need to remember to use e.g. \alph{} rather than \the....

@campa well yes I'm sure that it is related to cleveref. But the reason this time is not the edef, but that there is an \expandafter missing in various places. cleveref should do \csname p@#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname instead of \csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname

cleveref misses to expand a \csname following the p@counter command and so it not compatible with your \labelformat. Your example works with the following patches. This catches only the two main places. On the whole there are 31 occurrences in cleveref where \csname p@# is used and that should be corrected in the same way.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{counterOne}
\newcounter{counterTwo}
\newcounter{counterThree}
\renewcommand{\thecounterTwo}{\alph{counterTwo}}

\labelformat{counterTwo}{\textbf{\thecounterOne.(#1)}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\refstepcounter@noarg{\csname p@#1\endcsname}{\csname p@#1\expandafter\endcsname}{}{\fail}
\patchcmd\refstepcounter@optarg{\csname p@#2\endcsname}{\csname p@#2\expandafter\endcsname}{}{\fail}

% with hyperref
%\patchcmd\H@refstepcounter{\csname p@#1\endcsname}{\csname p@#1\expandafter\endcsname}{}{\fail} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{counterOne}
\refstepcounter{counterTwo}
\stepcounter{counterThree}

\label{here} Here

\refstepcounter{counterTwo}

\label{there} There

It was \ref{here}.

It was \ref{there}.
\end{document}


Thanks. I've emailed the author of the package.
